# Must change to plural?

Tags: gramática

Should I have to pluralize the "unas" and the "faldas" in this sentence if both sisters are wearing black skirts?

> Las hermanas Guzmán llevan unas faldas negros.

Comment: Si, menos ambos usan solo una falda.

Comment: Unas faldas **negras** suena mejor.

Comment: @jlliagre No es que suene. Debe ser así.

Comment: If the noun ("fald**as**") is feminine and plural, then must also be feminine and plural both article ("un**as**") and adjective ("negr**as**") that determine it.

Comment: @Ustanak Claro que debe, es lo que quería decir jocosamente.

Answer (score 7):

I disagree this time with both of the two former answers.

As far as I can tell, in Spanish these two constructions are valid:

> Las hermanas Guzmán llevan unas faldas negras.
>
> Las hermanas Guzmán llevan falda negra.

This is possible since common sense tells us that they cannot be wearing the same skirt at the same time.

The former idea is even valid if you say something like this:

> Las hermanas Guzmán llevan la misma falda negra.

because in that case, it is understood that they are wearing the *same model* of skirt.

So, there's no risk in using *falda* in singular, even if there is more than one person involved.

---

As a side note, these other sentences are also valid:

> Las hermanas Guzmán **llevan** una falda negra.
>
> Las hermanas Guzmán **llevan puesta** una falda negra.
>
> Las hermanas Guzmán **están usando** una falda negra.

Comment: I agree. If I hear or read "María y Ana llevaban un vestido rojo" I don't think, even for a second, that they where stuffed inside a single dress.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. Sentences like _los miembros del equipo español visten camiseta roja y pantalón azul_ are quite common. In fact, if I hear something like _visten camisetas rojas y pantalones azules_, it sounds kind of strange to me.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, otherwise they would both be wearing one skirt, which would be weird, unless perhaps they were Siamese twins. But whoever heard of someone from Siam named Guzman?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, direct object, ***unas faldas negras*** needs to match the subject ***las hermanas*** in noun. Also, note that ***faldas*** is a feminine name in Spanish, so the adjective, ***negras***, needs to match in genre as well.